# Macros Query - Copy Content

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am placing check boxes in my word document after certain sections.

I want to copy those contents under the checkbox when marked, and ignore if the checkbox is not marked using macros.

I this possible?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Post your current code if you get stuck

Comment: Hi David, Kind of looking for a start now! :/

Comment: What is your current status with the project? Have you worked with vba before? Have you written/recorded any code yet?

Comment: I have written vba codes but not for requirements like these.. btw i havent started yet

Comment: I would suggest to start by recording a macro that roughly does the task you want to automate and then look at the code of that macro. If you get stuck, just post the code in question here.

Comment: Done.. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Run()
'Declare the Worksheets
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet

'Set the worksheets to the appropriate variables
Set Ws = Sheets("DataSheet1")
Set Ws1 = Sheets("DataSheet1Copy")

'An if Loop to work only when the checkbox is enabled
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1 Then
        Ws1.Activate
        Cells.Select
        Selection.ClearContents
        Ws.Activate
        Cells.Select
        Cells.Copy
        Ws1.Activate
        Cells.PasteSpecial
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    End If
End Sub
```

I have written a VBA Code to copy the data only when the checkbox is enabled. Kindly go through the code and try to write accordingly for your logic. Let me know if this doesn't work.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Shapes("Check Box 1").OLEFormat.Object.Value = 1
```

This will be key for you logic as well and you can always specify your data ranges for copying inside the loop